# Selenium NullPointerException while trying to find WebElement

Tags: selenium, xpath, nullpointerexception, selenium-webdriver

While trying to execute below method, I receive NullPointerException:

```
@Test
public static void test1() {  
System.out.print("\nTo find UserName element");
WebElement element =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='email']"));
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
element.sendKeys("abhinav_shankar");
System.out.print("\nElement found");
System.out.print("\njunittest2 class-test1 executed before sleep");
Thread.sleep(15000);
System.out.print("\njunittest2 class-test1 executed after sleep");
}
```

Below excpetion is caught at line "WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));"

```
Thread [main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))  
    Mytestclass.test1() line: 44    
    Mytestclass.main(String[]) line: 21
```

I tried using xpath as written in above code but it also gives same error.

EDIT:

```
@BeforeClass 
public static void openbrowser() {  
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(); 
    System.out.print("\nBrowser open"); 
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile); 
    driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
    driver.get("website-url"); 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that driver is NOT null? Has the driver been initialized? Please provide the complete code if possible.

Comment: Driver is not null, it has initialized. Browser opens and webiste links also opens up. Following is the code: 
@BeforeClass
public static void openbrowser() { 
 FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(); 
 System.out.print("\nBrowser open");
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile); 
 driver.manage().window().maximize();
 driver.get("website-url");
}

Comment: @Abinav, provide the complete code if possible.

Comment: Following is the code: 
@BeforeClass
public static void openbrowser() { 
 FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(); 
 System.out.print("\nBrowser open");
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile); 
 driver.manage().window().maximize();
 driver.get("https://<website-url>");
}

Comment: WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);  --remove WebDriver here. Just try    driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have declared **driver** twice.  One in the class level & one in openbrowser method.

You initialize only the openbrowser driver. The class level driver is still null. So, test1 method throws null pointer exception.

So, remove the driver re-declaration in the openbrowser method. Just this will do and it should work.

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue** :
Your Webdriver objects seems to be declared inside a function openbrowser() because of which driver object scope is only with that function. So the NullpointerException could be due to driver.

**Solution** :
Declare the Webdriver globally and initialize within the openbrowser method so that you can use it in test1() or any other methods also.

```
public WebDriver driver;
@BeforeClass 
public static void openbrowser() {  
//Driver initialization
}

@Test
public static void test1() {  
//Use the driver here
}
```